# Most efficient way to perform rastercalculations with GeoTIFF and/or ErdasImagine files greater than 100gb

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, erdas-imagine, big-data

I have many GeoTIFFs ranging from 50-300gb and expect I'll have some even larger in the near future. I running a simple subtraction on a pair 77gb 1-band files, but I will also have similar 6-band files for which I need to generate a difference image. I have a machine with 28 physical cores and 256gb of ram. My current gdal_calc is using one CPU and the memory usage has been slowly climbing to 14gb over the last several hours and the gdal_calc progress meter is up to 5%. Any tips for speeding up this process?

EDIT: As requested, at the moment I have WD external 18tb drives running over a usb 3.1 connection.  As I write this I realize I am reading and writing to the same drive. I've restarted now writing to an internal 18tb drive.

This is the command that's now 43% done after 19hours.

gdal_calc -A R:\LidarCurrentNad83_1ft.img --A_band=1 -B R:\DSM_19_c49.img --B_band=1 --outfile=W:\RawCHMNad83_1ft.img --calc="B-A"

Here's the gdalinfo from layer A

```
 Driver: HFA/Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
Files: cnty49_LidarCurrentNad83_1ft_bi_.img
       cnty49_LidarCurrentNad83_1ft_bi_.img.aux.xml
       cnty49_LidarCurrentNad83_1ft_bi_.ige
Size is 191532, 208032
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["NAD83 / Washington South (ftUS)",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6269]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",45.3333333333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-120.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",45.8333333333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",47.3333333333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",1640416.66666667,
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (714338.613627773360349,553866.995222730794922)
Pixel Size = (1.081495520330806,-0.992400207660360)
Metadata:
  DataType=Generic
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  714338.614,  553866.995) (124d11'55.32"W, 46d47'33.40"N)
Lower Left  (  714338.614,  347415.995) (124d 9'37.66"W, 46d13'37.56"N)
Upper Right (  921479.614,  553866.995) (123d22'20.02"W, 46d48'58.55"N)
Lower Right (  921479.614,  347415.995) (123d20'33.06"W, 46d15' 1.84"N)
Center      (  817909.114,  450641.495) (123d46' 6.52"W, 46d31'20.53"N)
Band 1 Block=64x64 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Layer_1
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+38
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
```

Comment: Neither RAM nor cores will help with this task. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on the disk device(s) in use on the system

Comment: Maybe you would like to test how the derived bands in VRT behaves https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html. There seems to be a default pixel function "diff" for you. Unfortunately the usage looks somewhat complicated.

Comment: Tile them and parallelise the process across tiles

Comment: The tile route is what I've been wondering. I've read about the internal tiles, but I assume you mean cut them into many pieces and run as parallel tasks, then stitch back together.

Comment: Are they tiled? Compressed? Can you put them on SSD?

Comment: Would compression help? They are not, but I figured if they were they would need to uncompress to perform the math then recompress?

Comment: While USB 3.1 is not as bad at USB 2.x, you really want SSD or M.2 when working with large datasets (it's a two order of magnitude difference in performance, <1ms vice < 100ms seek)

Comment: I repeat a previous question: Are the source images tiled? and ask another one: Do you write the output as tiled? Add gdalinfo about the block size of some source image and show the creation options that you have used with gdal_calc.

Comment: Your are using ERDAS img format https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hfa.html for input and output. The format has internal tiles and it should be rather light to read and write. Maybe you could do a test with a tiled GeoTIFF output later (with `-co TILED=YES) and compare the speed. Testing with smaller images is faster.

Comment: Please edit the title because you do not have GeoTIFFs but ERDAS Imagine .img files. That probably does not affect the speed, though.

Comment: Are you comfortable with a python script doing this?

Comment: good catch, I'm using both geotiffs and imagine files in different places.

Comment: I do about 90% of my work with python scripts

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some time ago, but inside a C++ program that already linked with GDAL. What worked good enough (probably not the best) was a thread reading, a thread computing, and a thread writing. The chunks were 4096x4096 in size, but that depends a lot on other conditions. In your machine you could read (and write) bigger chunks of data.
See that if input is in "tiles", the output must be as well. If the input is in "strips", the output must be as well. But do not mix both patterns, or you will loose a lot of time (and disk space if you use compression, something that you have not mentioned).

Surprisingly in my case writing was not the bottle neck, but reading. So I configured two different threads reading different parts of the image, each one on a different GDAL dataset. (GDAL datasets are NOT thread-safe, neither for reading!). Writing must be in a single thread.
(If you are fine with a final VRT, you can write several files on the output and combine them in a VRT).

Maybe too much work, playing with threads here and there. It looks like the disk throughput will be the limitation, and 28 cores may not help that much. Let us know ;)

When you address the multiband use case, see that the pixel storage (RGBRGB or RRGGBB) is important. I was loosing a lot of time reading each band separately when I should read all of the bands in one shot (as I had RGBRGB).

Answer (score 2):

This is more a general IT issue than a GIS one. If you think of computing as a triangle with legs CPU, RAM, and Disk, where the area enclosed by the lines is computing power,

[image]

you've configured your system as a triangle that looks like this:

[image]

Even though your disk has a lot of storage, the seek time of an 18TiB WD disk unit is only really adequate for overnight backups (12-20ms). If you had gotten half the RAM and CPU and used the difference in price for high-performance disk drives (2x8Tb SSD at <1ms), you'd have much better image processing performance. Even a set of high quality HDDs would provide better throughput.

Comment: Definitely may need for specific processing drives. This machine has about 12 of these 18tb drives hooked up to it. SSD c drive and a couple big internal drives. ArcPro did this calculation on about 5 hours. I'm suprised gdal is this much slower. Again makes me think I'm doing it wrong. The many cores and ram are vital for other things we run.

Answer (score 2):

While ive not worked with Rasters quite as Large as you are suggesting, I have had some success with very large Rasters in GDAL using the following.

First thing I would reccomend, if your not currently doing it, is to work in command line as opposed to using GDAL within QGIS..etc.

Secondly have you tried setting the CACHE available to GDAL, I utilise the following..

```
set GDAL_CACHEMAX=90%
```

More information [HERE](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html) You can input this before you run any gdal script, I find it helps quite a lot. you can tweak the precentage value to suit your own setup.

Third suggestion would be to utilise the Creation Options in the creation of your GeoTiff. I find the following works great

```
--co "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS" --co "BIGTIFF=YES" --co "TILED=YES" --co "COMPRESS=LZW"
```

More information can be found [HERE](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html). I find this will help to reduce the size of your Rasters and also improve viewing them on desktop GIS. Again, you can tweak this to suit your own requirements.

Thirdly, if you are just looking to make them more efficient for viewing,you could look at creating Overviews with **gdaladdo**

Answer (score 2):

Here give this a shot. It uses the block read capability in rasterio to read in a large amount of data before doing the band math and writing the result, which will take advantage of your large amount of memory. As long as there is not a lot of fragmentation it should decrease the amount of seeks significantly. Increase the `sequential_block_reads` number to increase the amount of memory used. Note this assumes the crs, transform, height, and width are identical for the 2 input rasters.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from tqdm import tqdm

from itertools import islice

def batched(iterable, n):
    "Batch data into lists of length n. The last batch may be shorter."
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        batch = list(islice(it, n))
        if not batch:
            return
        yield batch

sequential_block_reads = 15

a_pointer = rasterio.open('R:\LidarCurrentNad83_1ft.img')
b_pointer = rasterio.open('R:\DSM_19_c49.img')

dest_profile = a_pointer.profile.copy()

with rasterio.open('W:\RawCHMNad83_1ft.img', 'w', **dest_profile) as outfile:

    blocks = [i for i in a_pointer.block_windows(1)]
    
    batched_blocks = batched(blocks, n=sequential_block_reads)
    
    for this_batch in tqdm(batched_blocks):
        
        # Read in this set of blocks at once. One file at a time to keep
        # hard drive seeks to a minimum.
        a_data = []
        for block_i, (block_index, block_window) in enumerate(this_batch):
            a_data.append(a_pointer.read(window=block_window))
        
        b_data = []
        for block_i, (block_index, block_window) in enumerate(this_batch):
            b_data.append(b_pointer.read(window=block_window))
        
        # Do the math for each block in this batch
        dest_data = []
        for a, b in zip(a_data, b_data):
            dest_data.append(
                b-a
                )
        
        # Write out the result
        for block_i, (block_index, block_window) in enumerate(this_batch):
            outfile.write(dest_data[block_i], window=block_window)
        
        # Clear out memory
        dest_data = a_data = b_data = None
```